# getLoginStatus not firing callback function

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, phonegap-plugins

I know this question has been asked before on SO but none of the resolutions stated have helped. The main difference with my situation is I'm using PhoneGap's  FaceBook SKD. I don't think that in itself is causing the issue but I'll let you be the judge of that. Here is some simple code I have tested with.

```
facebookConnectPlugin.getLoginStatus(
    function( response ) 
    {
        alert( response.status );
    }, true
);
```

This code works great at first. It seems like leaving the app logged in for awhile causes the issue but I'm not positive. All I can say for sure is that the functions callback stops firing and I have to force a logout to resolve the issue.

```
facebookConnectPlugin.logout(
    function( result ) 
    { 

    },
    function( error ) 
    { 

    }
);
```

This leads me to believe there is an issue with the login status being cashed. You may have noticed the second parameter being set to true in the first snippet. To my understanding that should force getLoginStatus to ignore the cashed data. As per the following info which I got for another post on SO

> “To improve the performance of your application, not every call to
>   check the status of the user will result in request to Facebook's
>   servers. Where possible, the response is cached. The first time in the
>   current browser session that FB.getLoginStatus is called, or the JS
>   SDK is init'd with status: true, the response object will be cached by
>   the SDK. Subsequent calls to FB.getLoginStatus will return data from
>   this cached response.
>
> This can cause problems where the user has logged into (or out of)
>   Facebook since the last full session lookup, or if the user has
>   removed your application in their account settings.
>
> To get around this, you call FB.getLoginStatus with the second
>   parameter set to true to force a roundtrip to Facebook - effectively
>   refreshing the cache of the response object.”

Any ideas on how I can fix this issue?